# Temporarily disabling triggers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I have been tasked with creating buttons inside of cells using Google Sheets.  Since GAS does not natively allow for buttons aside from using images, I decided to use data validation to get the job done.  I created data validations instead of buttons with singular entries, and used the onEdit trigger to fire a script whenever that cell's value is changed to the value in the list.

The script fires as expected when the cell initially changes.  However, I cannot find a way to change the value in the pseudobutton back to its original value without triggering the onEdit trigger again.  Here is the backing code to a relatively simple button from my sheet:

```
// If Delete Standard button is pressed
} else if (cell.getColumn() == 1 
           && cell.getRow() >= 8 
           && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() == analysisSheet.getName() 
           && cell.getDisplayValue != "X") {
  Browser.msgBox("Deleted Standard: " + analysisSheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), 3).getDisplayValue(), Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  analysisSheet.deleteRow(cell.getRow());
```

The cells in the column that contains the data validation have a value of "X", and that value is changed to "Remove this standard".  This triggers an onEdit function, which deletes the selected row.  Sometimes this only deletes one row, but most of the time, it also deletes the following row, and in a few cases, three rows.  I tried to restrict access to the function by stating that the selected cell value cannot be "X", but it appears that on the second trigger, it still has access to this portion of the code.  Yes, Browser.msgBox gets triggered for each row that is deleted.

My question is, is there a way to temporarily disable triggers to prevent this behavior from happening?  I have tried using the following without luck:

```
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
lock.waitLock(3000);
```

Edit:  Looks like I forgot parenthesis after the getDisplayValue method which fixes this issue.  However, I'd still like some sort of workaround for temporarily disabling triggers.

Comment: Why don't you use the menu that can be created with onOpen they way more nicer than this trick: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Comment: The idea was to create a work around for in-sheet buttons.  The people who are employing me for this project wanted buttons, because they found them more intuitive.  Additionally, the menu would become quite lengthy if I did that due to the large numbers of rows/columns in the sheet.  But that is still a nice idea for some of the other functionalities I will be adding, so thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: If you found the solution for your problem, please post it as an answer instead to append it as an edit to the question.

Comment: I am looking for a way to temporarily disable triggers.  While this edit allows my code to run as expected (for this particular button), other parts of my code still require a work around.  Therefore, this didn't actually answer my question.

Comment: I think that you should edit or post a new question. As it is, it look to be a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add / remove your triggers via script. Luckily this doesn't delete the execution history. It's functionally equivalent to disabling the trigger. Here's an example of creating and deleting triggers, although I  know yours is an onedit:

```
function createTimers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('calendar_test_occurred')
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(10)
      .everyMinutes(1) 
      .create();

}

function deleteTimers() {
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    if (triggers[i].getEventType() == ScriptApp.EventType.CLOCK) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I use check-box validation for buttons. I only run the code if the value is true, and then the script sets the range back to false at the end.